# Access button in code behind c#

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a button in my xaml code "Check" and want to set it visibility to hidden or visible based on the version of the application that is running. I am currently trying to set it through pragma statements in the constructor but it says the name doesn't exist

XAML code:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource Main.Button}" Name="Check"
    Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" Content="Check Configured Units" Width="150"
    Height="{StaticResource Main.Button.Height}"  />
```

C# code behind:

```
public partial class SinglePlayerSummaryView : UserControl
{
    public SinglePlayerSummaryView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

#if ReleaseStandard
        Check.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
#else
        Check.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
#endif
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: please try giving x:Name instead of Name in the xaml

Comment: Thank you, I actually had a mix up in my code but this works perfect to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the XAML giving the name to your control with x:Name

```
 <Button x:Name="Check" Style="{DynamicResource Main.Button}" Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" Content="Check Configured Units" Width="150" Height="{StaticResource Main.Button.Height}"  />
```

Then in your code:

```
public partial class SinglePlayerSummaryView : UserControl
{
    public SinglePlayerSummaryView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       #if ReleaseStandard
            this.Check.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
       #else
            this. Check.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
       #endif
    }
}
```

It might work.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had a mix up in my code but this works perfect to!